# soulution for Patch Fastbroadcast in ns2.35

Tags: broadcast, ns2

i want to patch FastBroadcast on ns2.35,already patch LTE in ns2.35,but in patch FastBroadcast the problem is,it not going to be completely patched .
dose it only work for ns2.29??
error is:

`Hunk #1 FAILED at 333. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file ns-2.35/Makefile.in.rej`

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume ns-2.35 patched with LTE-ns235_2014-2.patch .

The fastbroadcast patch was made from fastbroadcast_ns235.patch : Fastbroadcast-for-LTE-patched_ns235.patch https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNX3RLY1pDWmFRRFE/view?usp=sharing

Using the patch with an LTE patched ns-2.35 :

```
cd ns-allinone-2.35/
patch -p0 < Fastbroadcast-for-LTE-patched_ns235.patch
./install
```

Note: Not sure the fastbroadcast examples are working OK with an LTE patched ns2. I guess you can find a solution.

All patches https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNZ2lWZDBRSW40Q00?usp=sharing

All examples https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing

Broadcast examples https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNOUMyQjF1OWhTUlU/view?usp=sharing

LTE examples 06.17 https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNSmd4Q3h3dXp1QWc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i use fast broadcast in ns2.35,but when i run the example of broadcast.tcl this error is generated:                                                                             >Invalide class id in DropTail::enque, Packet's class id is 4

Comment: `Invalide class id in DropTail::enque ...` : Yes, happens when LTE is added. See my answer : ""I guess you can find a solution.""

Comment: i used from ns235-fastbroadcast & ns235-lte for run example lte runs , but broadcast dose not run and this error: >Invalide class id in DropTail::enque, Packet's class id is 4

Comment: I tested  another ns2   on another  ubuntu, but still this error is created 
Please help me, I need a lot of these two patches

Comment: ubuntu 15.04 and 64bit

Comment: i comment out this  section from drop-tail.cc :                                         >>> /*    hdr_ip *iph=HDR_IP(p);
    
    if(iph->flowid()!=0 && iph->flowid()!=1 && iph->flowid()!=2 && iph->flowid()!=3) 
    {
        printf("Invalide class id in DropTail::enque, Packet's class id is %d\n", iph->flowid());
        exit(0);
    } */   and solved

Comment: Is there an example of working  FastBroadCast with network LTE
If available, you can give it to me
Thanks